# Java/XML: What's the best way to decode/decompress a stream of data on the fly?

Tags: java, xml

In this case, I am SAX parsing an XML file that contains an element of Base64 encoded, zlib compressed data.  I know how to decode and decompress the data.  The issue is that I don't want to do it all in memory at once.  I want to do it in chunks, decoding/decompressing on the fly -- chunk by chunk.

My approach was this...

```
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
  // make a new string from ch
  // decode -- I think I need to make sure the String length is a multiple of 4?
  // create ByteArrayInputStream from the String
}
```

I have a class that extends `FilterInputStream` which holds the multiple `ByteArrayInputStreams` until they are ready to be read.  It still has bugs, but it's getting there.  I am wondering if this approach makes sense or if I'm reinventing the wheel here.  Is there an easier way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just use the `FilterInputStream`, it is all you need.